# Sampling identical sequences from two urns with unique colored balls

Tags: probability, sampling, combinatorics, hypergeometric-distribution

In very simple terms, my problem is as follows: given two urns, both with N balls where each ball has a unique color, I am interested in sampling sequences of N balls without replacement from each urn.

For example, given urns A = {R, G, B} and B = {R, G, B}, I would sample two sequences without replacement until the urns are empty, e.g., I could sample RBG from A and BRG from B, etc.

I'm trying to work out the answer to two questions:

- What is the probability of sampling two completely identical sequences?
- What is the probability of sampling two completely identical sequences if different colors have different probabilities? E.g., suppose A's probabilities are [0.5, 0.3, 0.2] and B's are [0.4, 0.3, 0.3] for R, G, and B respectively?

I would also like to understand better how this problem relates to multivariate hypergeometric distributions. In that case, if I understand correctly, we're sampling uniformly (e.g., what are my chances of drawing 7 women if I *uniformly* sample 10 people out of a population of 1400 women and 600 men), but in my case here the sampling need not be uniform. What is this sort of distribution called?

Comment: A "sequence without replacement" is known as a *permutation.*  Generating random permutations is a standard algorithm taught in CS courses--you can find implementations here on CV.  The answer to your first bulleted question is simple--think about it a little.  It's a special case of the second, *but the second is ambiguous:* please explain to us what these probabilities mean when you sample without replacement.  For instance, in urn A, suppose the red ball is the first one drawn.  What, now, are the probabilities of the green and blue balls?  *They cannot be 0.3 and 0.2 anymore.*

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the first one is simple, the reason I'm asking it is so I can set up the second question with non-uniform probabilities. To resolve the ambiguity: suppose I sample the red ball, then the green and blue ball probabilities in urn A would be 0.3/(0.3+0.2) and 0.2/(0.3+0.2) respectively. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does.  But now the answer is horribly messy, because it potentially contains different terms for every one of the $N!$ possible permutations in each urn and not much simplification is possible.